# NuGet Package restore failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am creating an 'ASP.NET Core MVC4' Demo project. When I am compiling it on another computer it outputs an error as follows:

> `Error    2   NuGet Package restore failed for project MVCDemo: Unable to find version '5.0.0' of    package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm'..`

What is the solution for this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install it manually using nuget package manager `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Edm -Version 5.0.0.50403`. I can just find this version [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Edm/). The latest version seems to be `EdmLib for OData v1-3 5.6.3`. Mostly, the package manifest from your previous machine had 5.0.0 instead of 5.0.0.50403

Answer (score 6):

ye, if you're stuck, just manually change your `packages.config` from `5.0.0` to `5.0.0.50403`. That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. This is the quickest and most straightforward fix.

Answer (score 0):

My error was

> an error occured while trying to restore packages. unable to find '5.6.4' of package 'Microsoft.Data.oData'**

I accessed `packages.config`, then deleted the line (mine was `Microsoft.OData`), went back to NuGet and re-installed `OData`. After that I was able to install `NewtonSoft` from NuGet